# How to search within a text file from a users input than print it using python?

Tags: python, file, input, text

I am having troubles trying to read multiple lines within a text file using python. My issue is, taking a users specific input and finding that piece of text and printing it out with multiple lines following it. I am trying to keep this within a `while` function by using `elif` to continue this part. This code is to take a users U.S State that was inputted and print that state following with the capitol of that state and state bird. This is done by reading in a text file containing the information of all 50 states. This is the code that I am currently working with. This is a small part of a menu that I am working on.

```
 elif x == "2":
    f = open("States and Capitals.txt", "r")
    x = input("Enter the state you would like to search: ") 
    searchlines = f.read()
    for x, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if x in line:
            for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print l,
        print(x)
    f.close()
```

Example of Text file:

Alabama

Capital: Montgomery

State Bird: Yellowhammer

State Flower: Camellia

Alaska

Capital: Juneau

State Bird: Willow Ptarmigan

State Flower: Forget Me Not

Arizona

Capital: Phoenix

State Bird: Cactus Wren

State Flower: Saguaro Cactus Blossom

Comment: what is the issue exactly?

Comment: I cant figure out how to add code to take a users input that will be used to find a state that is within a text file. After the code finds that specific text, It will print it.

Comment: why dont you save the input to variable like  x = input("enter value to search : ")

Comment: I have added this x = input ("\nPlease enter a State.\n") but do not know exactly how to have that input read through the text file and print just the input with the capital and bird.

Comment: Can you give some sample input from the `States and Capitals.txt` file so the format is clearly defined? I'm assuming for each state there are three lines, the name, the capital, and the state bird.

Comment: I added a few States in the example above

Comment: @MichaelMuscle please see my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can first split your file input into a list with the `split()` function, which in this case is using `"\n"` or `newline` as a delimiter. Then you just print the next 3 lines from the index or your found string (if it exists). Here I am assuming you want to print the state, the capital, the bird, and the flower (4 lines total).

```
elif x == "2":
    f = open("States and Capitals.txt", "r")
    x = input("Enter the state you would like to search: ") 
    searchlines = f.read().split("\n")
    if x in searchlines:
        index = searchlines.index(x)
        for i in range(4):
            print(searchlines[index+i])
    f.close()
```

If you want to exclude the State from the output because it is possibly redundant, then you can make the following minor alteration:

```
elif x == "2":
    f = open("States and Capitals.txt", "r")
    x = input("Enter the state you would like to search: ") 
    searchlines = f.read().split("\n")
    if x in searchlines:
        index = searchlines.index(x)
        for i in range(1,4):
            print(searchlines[index+i])
    f.close()
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much, I know that I may be bad at explaining code as I am fairly new at it, but this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
f = open("States and Capitals.txt", "r")
x = input("enter value to search : ") 
searchlines = f.read()
if(searchlines.find(x)):
    print(x)
f.close()
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for! There a way to add multiple lines after this? for example the Text file reads like this:    State name (next line down)
                                                                           State  capital (next line down) 
                                                                           State bird

Comment: what do you want  in the multiple lines?

Comment: Well I am looking to have the text file read from that specific state inputted and have the capital with the bird printed as well.

Comment: read from files line by line as in  for num, line in enumerate(f, 1): so you can get a control over the lines.

Comment: @Michael: You're now asking a different question from what's posted.

Comment: Does the updated code make alittle more sense? I am trying to take a users input, and make the code find that input in the text file and than print it out. But I am currently getting a syntax error for this line " for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print l,"

Comment: This is only determining if the value to search exists within the text file. The same method will not work for what the OP wants.

Comment: So how would I go about making this work? I'm confused on getting multiple lines to print out when a user searches for a specific Keyword. Example would be if a user inputs "Montana", the code will print "Montana" and the information (3 lines down) following this keyphrase. After the 3 lines down is the next State.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this may work. The result of this is you will get the variable output that has the line in it you want. You can then print that.

```
elif x == "2":
    state= input("\nPlease enter a State.\n")
    with open("States and Capitals.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if state.lower() in line.lower(): output=line
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to read the file three lines at time and prints the data from the state it finds that matches (if any):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

# See https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    ''' Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks. '''
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


target_state = input('Please enter a state name: ')

with open('States and Capitals.txt', 'r') as file:
    for group in grouper(file, 3, ''):  # Read file three lines at a time.
        state, capital, bird = map(str.rstrip, group)  # Remove newlines.
        if state == target_state:
            print(f'State: {state}, Bird: {bird}')
            break  # All done.
    else:
        print(f'Error: No state found named {target_state}')
```

Sample output:

```
State: Kansas, Bird: Western Meadowlark
```